# regex pattern for replacement of string

Tags: regex, xml

I am trying to replace the string with the below regex pattern but it is not getting replaced. I tried different combinations also but nothing worked. Any Idea?

```
<regex pattern="jre64\/1\.6\.0"
        replacement="jre64/1.7.0" />
```

Comment: May you describe us how we can test it?

Comment: Please provide a complete example and how you run this.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. It is the xslt which is is being used in the product and it suppose to remove the data from one text file. example below :-env.JVM_LIB_DIR=/data/4373/app/work/tibcojre64/1.6.0/lib/amd64

Comment: No, It is xml + xslt.